# Getting "subquery returns more than one row" error whenever trying to join a column from another table as alias?

Tags: mysql

I am stuck with this problem for a whole 2 days. I have a `users` table and it contains:

```
+--------+--------+----------+--------------------------------------------+
| userId |  name  | username |          profile_pic                       |
+--------+--------+----------+--------------------------------------------+
|      1 | john   | john123  | http://localhost/profile_pic/user1pic.jpg  | 
|      2 | andrew | andrew   | http://localhost/profile_pi/user2pic.jpg   |
|      3 | doe    | doe      | http://localhost/profile_pic/user3pic.jpg  |
+--------+--------+----------+--------------------------------------------+
```

I have another table called `userpost` which contains:

```
+--------+--------+-------------+----------------------------+
| postId | userId | postMessage |         postImage          |
+--------+--------+-------------+----------------------------+
|      1 |      1 | "Hey"       | http://localhost/post1.jpg |
|      2 |      3 | "Add me"    | http://localhost/post2.jpg |
|      3 |      2 | "boring"    | http://localhost/post3.jpg |
+--------+--------+-------------+----------------------------+
```

`userId` is refrenced to `users.userId`. I am trying to join `profile_pic` to `userpost` but mysql is returning error. Here is what I am doing:

```
 SELECT *, (SELECT profile_pic FROM users 
 INNER JOIN userpost on users.userId = userpost.userId) as profile_pic FROM userpost
```

But getting `Subquery returns more than 1 row` error

I know I am doing something stupid with the query. I just want something like this:

```
 +--------+--------+-------------+----------------------------+--------------------------------------------+    
 | postId | userId | postMessage |         postImage          |    profile_pic                             |
 +--------+--------+-------------+----------------------------+--------------------------------------------+
 |      1 |      1 | "Hey"       | http://localhost/post1.jpg | http://localhost/profile_pic/user1pic.jpg  | 
 |      2 |      3 | "Add me"    | http://localhost/post2.jpg | http://localhost/profile_pic/user3pic.jpg  | 
 |      3 |      2 | "boring"    | http://localhost/post3.jpg | http://localhost/profile_pi/user2pic.jpg   |
 +--------+--------+-------------+----------------------------+--------------------------------------------+
```

I am having a meeting tomorrow to showcase my prototype app. Help will be appreciated.

Comment: I think the userpost table contains more than one profile picture for each/any user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a sub query not a join. When using subquery in the select, you have to make sure it returns exacly one row like

```
SELECT COL1,COL2,(SELECT 1) from YourTable
```

Or by using a correlated query, which I assume was your purpose but is not required since its from the same table as you select, so just use a simple join:

```
SELECT s.*, t.profile_pic
FROM users t 
INNER JOIN userpost s on t.userId = s.userId
```

Comment: Nice. But your query leads to duplicated results when userpost have more than one profile picture for users.

Comment: @yossi I just want the `profile_pic` from users, not the whole users table.

Comment: @mikaeel I mixed up the aliases, take it now.

Comment: @SankarRaj Then they are not duplicates, and mikaeel should decide what he want to do with them.. If his could would work it would have resulted the same

Comment: @Yossi your updated query works the way I want. Just a question? Can I use your query in a long complex query?

Comment: What do you mean by long complex query? Basically yes, you can use it in almost any situation... @mikaeel

Comment: @Yossi i think your internet connection is low :"D

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
SELECT *, 
 (SELECT top 1 profile_pic FROM users a
 where a.userId = b.userId order by b.postId desc) as profile_pic 
 FROM userpost b
```

But i am not sure, the above query returns the desired profile picture.

Answer (score -1):

You are not using the sub-query correctly.you should make sure that sub-query will return only one row.

Below is the Query that you require.

```
Select up.postId,u.userId,up.postMessage,up.postImage,u.profile_pic from user u
inner join userpost up on u.userId=up.userId
```